# Implement shared tooltip in Grafana plugin developed using React

Tags: reactjs, grafana, syncfusion

I am developing a Grafana plugin (Smith Chart) using react. I have used Syncfusion library to implement the plugin. Everything in my plugin is working fine. Grafana launched a new feature (Shared Tooltip) in Grafana version 4.1, [Shared ToolTip in Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/guides/whats-new-in-v4-1/). I have to use this feature in my plugin too, i didn't find any development instructions on grafana website. How can i implement this feature in my own plugin ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Error of my code is:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

We have analysed your query. We suggest an option to enable crosshair and tooltip property to display tooltip as like chart denoted in provided link. We are having a demo link for your reference. Please check with below links.

**Code Snippet**

```
 <ChartComponent id='charts'
             tooltip={{ enable: true, shared: true }}
             crosshair={{ enable: true, lineType: 'Vertical' }}>
 </ChartComponent>
```

**Screenshots**

[image: Crosshair]

[image: Trackball]

**Demo Links**

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/chart/trackball
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/chart/local-data

Kindly revert us, if you have any concerns.

Regards,

Durga G

Comment: No its not working. One thing to let you know is that i am using "SmithchartSeriesDirective". I have edited the question and posted the error which i am getting after doing the changes which you have mentioned.